# Adding Elements to a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have used BeautifulSoup parser to parse an xml document. Here is the code below. I want to put all the elements into a single dictionary.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

f = open('/home/soundarya/Desktop/mv-v18-1526.nxml','r')

d = BeautifulSoup(f.read())

s = d.find('journal-meta')

j = s.findAll('journal-id')
print s.find('journal-title').renderContents()

print s.find('issn').renderContents()

print s.find('publisher-name').renderContents()

for x in j:
    print x.renderContents()
```

I got the output for this as elements :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py:166: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))
**Molecular Vision
1090-0535
Molecular Vision
Mol Vis
Mol. Vis
MV**
```

## I tried using like :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

f = open('/home/soundarya/Desktop/mv-v18-1526.nxml','r')

d = BeautifulSoup(f.read())

a = {}
a['journal-meta'] = d.find('journal-meta')
a['journal-id'] = a.find('journal-id')
a['journal-title'] = a.find('journal-title').renderContents()
a['issn'] = a.find('issn').renderContents()
a['publisher-name'] = a.find('publisher-name').renderContents()

for x in a:
    print x.renderContents()
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Help me to put the elements in a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a['journal-id'] = a.find('journal-id')
```

I think you wanted to use variable `d`:

```
a['journal-id'] = d.find('journal-id')
```

Generally, try to use more descriptive variable names.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. Any idea how do I put the dictionary as a json string?

Comment: You mean, how to serialize your dict as JSON? `import json; json_str = json.dumps(your_dict)`

Comment: getting this error : raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <publisher-name>Molecular Vision</publisher-name> is not JSON serializable

Comment: Your dict should contain only [serializable objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump). Ensure that keys of the dict are strings and values are str, unicode, int, long, float, bool, None.

Comment: thanks a lot.. i got it. I have a question now. 
I am parsing a xml document.. by specifying the meta-data entities like 
a = {}
a['journal-meta'] = d.find('journal-meta').renderContents()
a['journal-id'] = d.find('journal-id').renderContents()
like this. 
We have so many elements in the xml document. Is there anyway to dynamically parse the xml doc and get the data ? 
Looking forward to your reply. Thanks.

Comment: For effectively extracting data from html/xml docs I would use xpath. Please create new questions instead of posting them in the comments.